# C3JS bar chart with specific order with color

Tags: javascript, positioning, c3.js

i currently working on c3 chart to draw Stack bar chart. i can able to populate the dynamic data based on click event, its work fine but when i look into chart the bar chart which displayed in charts its not positioned properly based on my inputs [image]

Here i attach my Sample Code :

```
Rowvalue = [['1-10'].concat(processed_value_final0),
['11-50'].concat(processed_value_final1),
['51-200'].concat(processed_value_final2),
['201-500'].concat(processed_value_final3),
['501-1k'].concat(processed_value_final4)];
groupCol = ['1-10', '11-50', '51-200', '201-500', '501-1k'];  

var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: div_id,
    data: {
        columns:Rowvalue,    
        type: 'bar',
        order: 'asc',
        groups: [
            groupCol                                    
        ]
        },
        bar: {
            width: barwd
            } ,
        grid: {
            y: {
                show: true,
                lines: [{value:0}]
            }
            },
        axis: { 
            x: 
            {
                type: 'category',
                categories: keyValue
            },
            y:
            {
                min : 0,
                padding : {
                bottom : 0
                }                                    
            }
        },
    color: {
        pattern: ['#ED5565', '#23C6C8', '#F8AC59', '#1AB394', '#1C84C6', '#F8AC59', '#23C6C8', '#ED5565', '#F8AC59']
        },
    legend:
    {
    show: true,
    position:'right'
    },
    tooltip :
    {
    show:true
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the value in the `order` section of the configuration, which can be either i) `'asc'` or `'desc'` - which work on data values i.e. biggest or smallest values first, ii)| `null` for the same (but not, see later) ordering as the data, or iii) an array of the data series keys or iv) a function that operates on the data series keys.

Here we change the order to be an array - the groupCol array but reversed:

```
    order: groupCol.reverse(),
```

This changes the order to be the reverse of the ordering defined in groupCol and rowValue variables. The reason it needs to be reversed is because the stack drawing algorithm starts from the bottom up while the legend key lists the data series keys from the top down. This is also why the `null` option wouldn't work, the bars and the legend would be reversed in order from each other.